# Clarifying Probability Mass Function (PMF)

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I am currently reading *Deep Learning book*, and I want to get better understanding of probability theory. In chapter ***3.3.1*** of *Deep Learning book* it states that:

> Often we associate each random variable with a diﬀerent probability
>   mass function and the reader must infer which PMF to use based on the
>   identity the random variable, rather than on the name of the
>   function;P(x) is usually not the same as P (y).

And not many paragraphs latter, it saids the following:

> Probability mass functions can act on many variables at the same time.
>   Such a probability distribution over many variables is known as a joint
>   probability distribution.P(x=x, y=y) denotes the probability
>   that x=x and y=y simultaneously. We may also write P (x, y) for brevity

I am having hard time grasping these two paragraphs. What do they mean when they say that `P(x)` is **USUALLY** not the same as `P(y)`. As I understood, random variable is basically a random phenomenon from a real world that we wish to model. And each random phenomenon has its own Probability Mass function. Does this mean that the first paragraph indicates that random variable `y` represents a different phenomenon, and in the second paragraph random variable `y` represents the same type of phenomenon as `x` and that is why we use the same probability mass function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe they mean the following: "We will use $P$ to denote the concept of a probability mass function (pmf). $P(x)$ is the pmf of random variable $x$, while $P(y)$ is the pmf of random variable $y$. The two variables are usually the results of different random experiments, hence we use two separate letters, $x$ and $y$. As such, they will probably have different pmfs. But somethimes, it might happen that they have the same."

I think the essential source of confusion is that $P$ is not used to denote any single pmf, but is the name used to refer to a pmf. As a parallel, height_of(Stefan) and height_of(Mark) may be different, or they may be the same. height_of is just the name of the thing we are measuring, not the thing itself.

P(x,y) is thus the pmf of the joint variable (x,y). P((x, y)) would be a more unambiguous notation, but I guess is omitted for brevity. If you need more clarification on joint variables let me know. I hope this helps.